# Download a file in AIr,Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I need to download a file for example say, a pdf file from a url and store it in applicationsDirectory or ApplicationStorage directory , I have a code to download but its opening save dialog box to get the userinput for where to save the downloaded file.

This is the code that I am using

`downloadURL.url = urlLocation;

           configureListeners(file);

           file.download(downloadURL);`

I need to download the file with out opening any window, and file needs to be downloaded to ApplicationStorage directory.

Thanks in advance

Comment: that can't possibly be all the code you're using?

Answer (score 2):

You need the File and FileStream Classes... first load what you need as a binary URLLoader, retrieve the ByteArray, and then save it to the location you want with something like this:

```
var file:File = new File(File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath+"/myfile.jpg");
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeBytes(bytes);
fileStream.close();
```

Where "bytes" is the bytearray you loaded...

Answer (score 0):

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader ();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest ();
request.url = "http://" + "your file adress here";
loader.load(request);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE , function (e:Event):void {
 var file:File = new File(File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath+"/yourfile name here");
 var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
 fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
 fileStream.writeBytes(loader.data);
 fileStream.close();
});
```

Comment: you can but only air because reason is security